# Add onclick property to input with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, input, onclick

I am creating a user input at one of the events:

```
var throwConnectBox = function() {
    chat_box = document.getElementById('box');
    div = window.parent.document.createElement('div');
    input = window.parent.document.createElement('input');
    input.type = "submit";
    input.value = "Join chat";
    input.onclick = "conn.send('$connect\r\n');";
    div.appendChild(input);
    chat_box.appendChild(div);
}
```

... but the resulting input does not have onclick property. I tried to use

```
    input.onclick = conn.send('$connect\r\n');
```

... instead, but didn' work either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you already declared all of those variables? If not, you're using "implied globals" which isn't very good—make them local variables by declaring them with the "var" keyword.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try this:

```
 input.onclick = function() { conn.send('$connect\r\n'); };
```

Steve

Comment: Tried it, but the input didn't get the onclick property. What might be going on there?

Comment: How are you determining whether the input got the "onclick" function or not?

Comment: I go to FireBug and look in the "HTML" section if it has it.

Comment: Interesting. I quickly tried creating an element with an "onclick" handler and adding it to the DOM, and it didn't show up in the HTML section (but the onclick handler was there and working). Try adding an ID attribute to the input (let's assume the ID is "test"), and execute the following code (without the single quotes) in Firebug's console: 'document.getElementById("test").onclick'. Do you get back a function?

Answer (score 6):

There is a problem with one of your lines here; I've corrected it for you:

```
 var throwConnectBox = function() {
     chat_box = document.getElementById('box');
     div = window.parent.document.createElement('div');
     input = window.parent.document.createElement('input');
     input.type = "submit";
     input.value = "Join chat";
     /* this line is incorrect, surely you don't want to create a string? */
     // input.onclick = "conn.send('$connect\r\n');";?
     input.onclick = function() { 
         conn.send('$connect\r\n'); 
     };
     div.appendChild(input);
     chat_box.appendChild(div);
 }
```

Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 2):

I think you may want to escape the \r\n, if you intend to pass these...

```
conn.send('$connect\\r\\n')
```

I don't quite see what your onclick handler tries to achieve...

Comment: Ah, no problem with that, it works fine (it sends a line via a TCP socket). I'm actually stuck with attaching the onclick property to the input tag.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the reasons why I've decided to use jQuery:

```
 $('<input type="submit" value="Join chat" />')
      .click( function() { conn.send('$connect\r\n'); } )
      .appendTo('<div></div>')
      .appendTo('#box');
```