# How do I add a simple onClick event handler to a canvas element?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, event-handling, onclick

I'm an experienced Java programmer but am looking at some JavaScript/HTML5 stuff for the first time in about a decade.  I'm completely stumped on what should be the simplest thing ever.

As an example I just wanted to draw something and add an event handler to it.  I'm sure I'm doing something stupid, but I've searched all over and nothing that is suggested (e.g. the answer to this question:  [Add onclick property to input with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789824/add-onclick-property-to-input-with-javascript)) works.  I'm using Firefox 10.0.1.  My code follows.  You'll see several commented lines and at the end of each is a description of what (or what doesn't) happen.

What's the correct syntax here?  I'm going crazy!

```
<html>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150"/>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        var elem = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        // elem.onClick = alert("hello world");  - displays alert without clicking
        // elem.onClick = alert('hello world');  - displays alert without clicking
        // elem.onClick = "alert('hello world!')";  - does nothing, even with clicking
        // elem.onClick = function() { alert('hello world!'); };  - does nothing
        // elem.onClick = function() { alert("hello world!"); };  - does nothing
        var context = elem.getContext('2d');
        context.fillStyle = '#05EFFF';
        context.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 100);
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Use `onclick` instead of `onClick`

Comment: To elaborate on why those attempts didn't work ... The first couple of comments display an alert immediately because you are calling `alert()` directly in `<script>`, instead of defining a function that will call `alert()`. The rest don't do anything because of the capitalization of `onclick`.

Comment: You can use this lib https://jsfiddle.net/user/zlatnaspirala/fiddles/ , looks at https://bitbucket.org/nikola_l/visual-js/ . You will get a lot of features +

Answer (score 282, accepted):

When you draw to a `canvas` element, you are simply drawing a bitmap in [immediate mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediate_mode_(computer_graphics)).

The *elements* (shapes, lines, images) that are drawn have no representation besides the pixels they use and their colour.

Therefore, to get a *click* event on a `canvas` *element* (shape), you need to capture click events on the `canvas` HTML element and use some math to determine which element was clicked, provided you are storing the elements' width/height and x/y offset.

To add a `click` event to your `canvas` element, use...

```
canvas.addEventListener('click', function() { }, false);
```

To determine which *element* was clicked...

```
var elem = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
    elemLeft = elem.offsetLeft + elem.clientLeft,
    elemTop = elem.offsetTop + elem.clientTop,
    context = elem.getContext('2d'),
    elements = [];

// Add event listener for `click` events.
elem.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var x = event.pageX - elemLeft,
        y = event.pageY - elemTop;

    // Collision detection between clicked offset and element.
    elements.forEach(function(element) {
        if (y > element.top && y < element.top + element.height 
            && x > element.left && x < element.left + element.width) {
            alert('clicked an element');
        }
    });

}, false);

// Add element.
elements.push({
    colour: '#05EFFF',
    width: 150,
    height: 100,
    top: 20,
    left: 15
});

// Render elements.
elements.forEach(function(element) {
    context.fillStyle = element.colour;
    context.fillRect(element.left, element.top, element.width, element.height);
});​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BmeKr/).

This code attaches a `click` event to the `canvas` element, and then pushes one shape (called an `element` in my code) to an `elements` array. You could add as many as you wish here.

The purpose of creating an array of objects is so we can query their properties later. After all the elements have been pushed onto the array, we loop through and render each one based on their properties.

When the `click` event is triggered, the code loops through the elements and determines if the click was over any of the elements in the `elements` array. If so, it fires an `alert()`, which could easily be modified to do something such as remove the array item, in which case you'd need a separate *render* function to update the `canvas`.

---

For completeness, why your attempts didn't work...

```
elem.onClick = alert("hello world"); // displays alert without clicking
```

This is assigning the return value of `alert()` to the `onClick` property of `elem`. It is immediately invoking the `alert()`.

```
elem.onClick = alert('hello world');  // displays alert without clicking
```

In JavaScript, the `'` and `"` are semantically identical, the lexer probably uses `['"]` for quotes.

```
elem.onClick = "alert('hello world!')"; // does nothing, even with clicking
```

You are assigning a string to the `onClick` property of `elem`.

```
elem.onClick = function() { alert('hello world!'); }; // does nothing
```

JavaScript is case sensitive. The `onclick` property is the archaic method of attaching event handlers. It only allows one event to be attached with the property and the event can be lost when serialising the HTML.

```
elem.onClick = function() { alert("hello world!"); }; // does nothing
```

Again, `' === "`.

Comment: Hmm...forgive me if I'm misunderstanding - but am I not capturing click events on the canvas element?  I'm not sure what you mean by *what* element was clicked.  There's only one element on this page, right?

Comment: He meant "which element within the canvas" - that is which "shape" so to say.

Comment: @jperovic That is exactly how I wrote my answer, I just called a shape an *element* in this example. Maybe it's the wrong word, it's a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks, very much so - though I'm not totally clear on the last one.  I'm following the example here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onclick (using the anonymous function that they describe) and it works, even when I change the span to a canvas.  So it won't be hard for me to slowly transform their example into mine to see what I'm doing wrong.  Thank you for the detailed response!  The explanation of why my various attempts were wrong were especially helpful.

Comment: @Jer No worries, if you have more questions, feel free to post and ping me on Twitter, [@alexdickson](https://twitter.com/alexdickson).

Comment: has anyone used this on canvas objects that move around? worried that it would only work on fixed positions. hmm but if it happens at the time of the click then it should work.

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax It should work fine, just update the positions of your objects in memory and use those definitions to render from

Comment: `elem.onClick = () => alert('Hello world');` and `elem.onClick => alert.bind(this, 'Hello world');` works too

Comment: @Kalanos yes you're right, this won't work if the canvas moves around, e.g. if it's centered on the page and the user resizes the window. To fix that, you can move the definitions of `elemLeft` and `elemTop` inside the event listener.

Comment: How would this code change to detect a mouse click on a  rotated rectangle?

Answer (score 48):

***2021:***

To create a trackable element in HTML5 canvas you should use the [new Path2D()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D/Path2D) method.

After creating your shapes with `new Path2D()` where a name is given for each one of them, listen to touch or mouse events (such as `onclick`, `ondblclick`, `oncontextmenu`, `onmousemove` or etc.) on your canvas to get the point coordinates `event.offsetX` and `event.offsetY` then use `CanvasRenderingContext2D.isPointInPath()` or `CanvasRenderingContext2D.isPointInStroke()` to precisely check if the mouse is hover your element in that event.

**IsPointInPath:**

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Create circle
const circle = new Path2D();
circle.arc(150, 75, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fill(circle);

// Listen for mouse moves
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  // Check whether point is inside circle
  if (ctx.isPointInPath(circle, event.offsetX, event.offsetY)) {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
  }
  else {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  }

  // Draw circle
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fill(circle);
});
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

**IsPointInStroke:**

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Create ellipse
const ellipse = new Path2D();
ellipse.ellipse(150, 75, 40, 60, Math.PI * .25, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.lineWidth = 25;
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
ctx.fill(ellipse);
ctx.stroke(ellipse);

// Listen for mouse moves
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  // Check whether point is inside ellipse's stroke
  if (ctx.isPointInStroke(ellipse, event.offsetX, event.offsetY)) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'green';
  }
  else {
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
  }

  // Draw ellipse
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fill(ellipse);
  ctx.stroke(ellipse);
});
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Example with multiple elements:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const circle = new Path2D();
circle.arc(50, 75, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fill(circle);

const circletwo = new Path2D();
circletwo.arc(200, 75, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fill(circletwo);

// Listen for mouse moves
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  // Check whether point is inside circle
  if (ctx.isPointInPath(circle, event.offsetX, event.offsetY)) {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
    ctx.fill(circle);
  }
  else {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fill(circle);
  }
  
    if (ctx.isPointInPath(circletwo, event.offsetX, event.offsetY)) {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.fill(circletwo);
  }
  else {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fill(circletwo);
  }
  
});
```

```css
html {cursor: crosshair;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

If you have a list of dynamic elements to be checked, you can check them in a loop, like this:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var elementslist = []

const circle = new Path2D();
circle.arc(50, 75, 30, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fill(circle);

const circletwo = new Path2D();
circletwo.arc(150, 75, 30, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fill(circletwo);

const circlethree = new Path2D();
circlethree.arc(250, 75, 30, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fill(circlethree);

elementslist.push(circle,circletwo,circlethree)

document.getElementById("canvas").addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
event = event || window.event;
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")

for (var i = elementslist.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){  

if (elementslist[i] && ctx.isPointInPath(elementslist[i], event.offsetX, event.offsetY)) {
document.getElementById("canvas").style.cursor = 'pointer';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'orange';
    ctx.fill(elementslist[i]);
return
} else {
document.getElementById("canvas").style.cursor = 'default';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    for (var d = elementslist.length - 1; d >= 0; d--){ 
    ctx.fill(elementslist[d]);
    }
}
}  

});
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

---

*Sources*:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D/Path2D
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInPath
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInStroke

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to alex's answer:

You could use a SVG drawing instead of a Canvas drawing. There you can add events directly to the drawn DOM objects.

see for example:

[Making an svg image object clickable with onclick, avoiding absolute positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296097/making-an-svg-image-object-clickable-with-onclick-avoiding-absolute-positioning)

Comment: sorry for the enthusiasm, it's just i had a problem for which using SVG is the obvious solution, and I hadn't thought of it until your comment ^^

Answer (score 3):

I recommand the following article : [Hit Region Detection For HTML5 Canvas And How To Listen To Click Events On Canvas Shapes](https://blog.lavrton.com/hit-region-detection-for-html5-canvas-and-how-to-listen-to-click-events-on-canvas-shapes-815034d7e9f8) which goes through various situations.

However, it does not cover the `addHitRegion` API, which must be the best way (using math functions and/or comparisons is quite error prone). This approach is detailed [on developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/addHitRegion)

Comment: "[`addHitRegion`] is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it." - from the dev.moz link you include, to save others a click.

Answer (score 2):

Probably very late to the answer but I just read this while preparing for my `70-480` exam, and found this to work -

```
var elem = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
elem.onclick = function() { alert("hello world"); }
```

Notice the event as `onclick` instead of `onClick`.

[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/yekojopota/edit?js,console,output) example.

Comment: The OP wants to add `onclick` to an element inside the canvas, but not the canvas itself

Answer (score 1):

You can also put DOM elements, like `div` on top of the canvas that would represent your canvas elements and be positioned the same way.

Now you can attach event listeners to these divs and run the necessary actions.

Comment: for dumb iOS programmers, it would be great to know how to do this  :)

Answer (score 1):

As another cheap alternative on somewhat static canvas, using an overlaying img element with a usemap definition is quick and dirty.  Works especially well on polygon based canvas elements like a pie chart.

Answer (score 0):

[Alex Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880279/how-do-i-add-a-simple-onclick-event-handler-to-a-canvas-element#answer-9880302) is pretty neat but when using context rotate it can be hard to trace x,y coordinates, so I have made a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Imran_Bughio/BmeKr/1163/) showing how to keep track of that.

Basically I am using this function & giving it the angle & the amount of distance traveled in that angel before drawing object.

```
function rotCor(angle, length){
    var cos = Math.cos(angle);
    var sin = Math.sin(angle);

    var newx = length*cos;
    var newy = length*sin;

    return {
        x : newx,
        y : newy
    };
}
```