# Onclick listener in canvas

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a problem with adding a basic onclick listener in canvas in javascript, I want to retrieve the (x, y) coordinates for it, I would appreciate any help please.

Thank you.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880279/how-do-i-add-a-simple-onclick-event-handler-to-a-canvas-element

Comment: I don't know what you already tried. But perhaps you try to add the event listener on the 2d context, not the canvas element. Anyway I recommand you to use http://raphaeljs.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this..

```
document.getElementById('canvasId').addEventListener('click',function(evt){
alert(evt.clientX + ',' + evt.clientY);
},false);
```