# HTML5 / JavaScript Clickevent on Image

Tags: javascript, html, onclicklistener

here comes my code first..

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="640" height="480">

</canvas>




<script type="text/javascript">
    // Javascript Goes Here
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var width = canvas.getAttribute('width');
    var height = canvas.getAttribute('height');

    //Images variables
    var bgImage = new Image();
    var playImage = new Image();
    var shipImage = new Image();
    var instructImage = new Image();
    var logoImage = new Image();

    //Arrays for position of Images
    var buttonX = [196, 196, 150, 160];
    var buttonY = [100, 140, 12, 150];
    var buttonWidth = [96, 260, 182, 160];
    var buttonHeight = [40, 40, 40, 40];




    //Source of Images
    bgImage.src = "Images/Background.png";
    playImage.src = "Images/play.png";
    //shipImage.src = "Images/enemy.png";
    instructImage.src = "Images/instructions.png";
    logoImage.src = "Images/logo.png";



    //drawing Images 
    bgImage.onload = function () {
        context.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0);
    };
    playImage.onload = function () {
        context.drawImage(playImage, buttonX[0], buttonY[0]);
    };
    instructImage.onload = function () {
        context.drawImage(instructImage, buttonX[1], buttonY[1])
    }
    logoImage.onload = function () {
        context.drawImage(logoImage, buttonX[2], buttonY[2])
    }
    //shipImage.onload = function () {
    //    context.drawImage(shipImage, buttonX[3], buttonY[3])
    //}
```

What i want to have is a simple ClickListener on the play and instruction image. I´ve tried many options and tutorials but nothing works....
Could anybody help me please?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: try this. It's a bit complex but i believe its a good start http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880279/how-do-i-add-a-simple-onclick-event-handler-to-a-canvas-element

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to register the handlers:

```
playImage.addEventListener("click", function(){
  alert("Play was clicked.");
});

instructImage.addEventListener("click", function(){
  alert("Instruct was clicked.");
});
```

Alternatively, this may also work for you:

```
playImage.onclick = function() { alert("Play was clicked."); };
instructImage.onclick = function () { alert("Instruct was clicked."); };
```

If that doesn't work for you, describe your expectations and how they aren't met by this answer.

Also, the following [link to the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) would help you with syntax questions like this in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am not very good at programming..so where should i drop the code ? I think i must write a new function or?

Comment: Used another option :) http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/animating-game-menus-and-screen-transitions-in-html5-a-guide-for-flash-developers--active-11183