# Detect which canvas rectangle is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I have a canvas in html:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="450" height="450"></canvas>
```

That I made nine equally sized squares in. I would like to see what square I have clicked as an alert function. How would I do that?

Full Code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/ckd6g1ac/1/

Sorry, I do not have any code relevant to my problem in the JSFiddle, but I have no clue on how to start writing it.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880279/how-do-i-add-a-simple-onclick-event-handler-to-a-canvas-element - this should help... so, some math... :)

Comment: Damn, marked as duplicate. I can still share this working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ckd6g1ac/8/

Comment: @Xufox thanks a lot man, you are the only one who provided an answer to this question.

Comment: @Xufox Put it as an answer man.

Comment: Ok, I’ve rewritten the answer (it was short, fortunately).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your `onclick` function:

```
$("#canvas").click(function(e) {
  var yNames = ['upper', 'middle', 'lower'],
    xNames = ['left', 'middle', 'right'];
  alert(('The '
    + yNames[Math.floor((e.offsetY * 3) / canvas.height)] + '-'
    + xNames[Math.floor((e.offsetX * 3) / canvas.width)] + ' box was clicked.')
      .replace('middle-middle', 'middle'));
});
```

Also you had a semantic error in your loop: it should be `i<9` instead of `1<9`.

`offsetX` and `offsetY` were used because these measure the offset from the element itself, which means that it doesn’t matter where the canvas is on the page.

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ckd6g1ac/8/).