# Js mouse click events

Tags: javascript, mouseclick-event

Is there an event function that activates if a mouse is clicked that goes like this:

```
var mouseclick = function(e) {
  if(e.mouseclick==true){
     alert("Hi");
   }
}
```

I'm trying to make it if i click a certain area of a canvas.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the `'click'` event:

```
var el = document.getElementById('my-div');
el.addEventListener('click', handleClick, true);

function handleClick() {
  alert('Hi');
}
```

See working snippet below:

```js
var el = document.getElementById('my-div');
el.addEventListener('click', handleClick, true);

function handleClick() {
  alert('Hi');
}
```

```css
#my-div {
  background-color: red;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px
}
```

```html
<div id="my-div">
  Click Me!
</div>
```

Here is the MDN Documentation for [`EventTarget.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want something to happen based on clicking on the canvas, check out this link: [How do I add a simple onClick event handler to a canvas element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880279/how-do-i-add-a-simple-onclick-event-handler-to-a-canvas-element)

Else if you want something to happen based on clicking a specific area of canvas, check out this link: http://pterkildsen.com/2013/06/28/create-a-html5-canvas-element-with-clickable-elements/

A quick google search yielded the above results.

Answer (score 0):

Are you simply trying to do something like this:

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
```

You can change the dom selector to anything you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Another easy solution that gives some degree of finesse is to use jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(ELEMENT).click(function(){
      //do stuff
   });

 });
```

Here you can explicitly specify which element you want to "listen to".