# Event listener assigned in a loop triggers all of them

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, dom-events

Every object in the `balls` array is assigned an event listener that alerts the object's color, but when you click on just one, it activates all of them, alerting the color of every single object in it.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/khanfused/rdso9fsk/12/), snippet (listen):

```
function listen(obj, map, event, callback) {
  map.addEventListener(event, function (e) {
    if (hasPoint(obj.getBounds() || obj, event.clientX, event.clientY)) {
      callback.call(obj, e);
    }
  });
}
```

Loop (handler assignment);

```
for (var b = 0; b < balls.length; b++) {
  (function(b) {
      listen(balls[b], map, 'click', function(e) {
        alert(this.color); // where `this` === balls[b]
      });
  }(b));
}
```

(note: #listen is contained in an external file on GitHub - utils.js)

How would I have each object only trigger its own event listener?

Comment: It looks like you're adding the event listener to map in the listen() function. Instead, maybe try obj.addEventListener( ...

Comment: `obj` is just a JavaScript object -- not a DOM element. It doesn't have #addEventListener.

Comment: I see.. then I think the problem is your if-condition:
hasPoint(obj.getBounds() || obj, event.clientX, event.clientY))

...what is this hasPoint function doing, and what does obj.getBounds() || obj do ?

It looks like all of the objects are returning true for that conditional check..

Comment: may be this answer must help you out solve the issue.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880279/how-do-i-add-a-simple-onclick-event-handler-to-a-canvas-element

Comment: No, my calculations are fine for detecting clicks on the balls. It's just the event fires for every ball, not just the one that was clicked.

Comment: Also, @miir, the `hasPoint` function returns whether or not the bounding rectangle of the object contains the mouse coordinates. It passes in the object itself if it doesn't have `#getBounds`, and assumes that it IS a rectangle with `width` and `height `properties. I don't think it is returning true for every object since I have an IIFE wrapping the listener which takes care of that particularly common problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The external `util.js` is key here, the listen function looks like

```
function listen(obj, map, event, callback) {
  map.addEventListener(event, function (e) {
    if (hasPoint(obj.getBounds() || obj, event.clientX, event.clientY)) {
      callback.call(obj, e);
    }
  });
}
```

And you use it like

```
listen(balls[b], map, 'click', function(e) {
    alert(this.color); // where `this` === balls[b]
});
```

Note that `event` in the `listen()` function is the string `click`, not the actual event, that would be `e`, so you want to use `e` to get the coordinates

```
function listen(obj, map, event, callback) {
  map.addEventListener(event, function (e) {
    if (hasPoint(obj.getBounds() || obj, e.clientX, e.clientY)) {
      callback.call(obj, e);
    }
  });
}
```

And that solves the issue

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/rdso9fsk/13/)

Comment: Yes, @adeneo is right, your map is a canvas and you are attaching events to the canvas.

Comment: But then how would I listen for a click on the balls?

Comment: By adding the listener on each ball, not on the entire canvas

Comment: I get it now, the issue is just using the wrong `event`

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.