# How do I make multiple buttons or image element eventlisteners on a canvas in html/javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, button, canvas

Im making a cookie clicker like game but i want it to be entirely in canvas. I've been looking around and the only few ways i can make a button / image onclick is either a `document.getElementById("image").addEventListener("click", function(){});`  thing or by making an actual button with html. But neither of these things are in canvas and drawn outside the canvas box. And im having multiple of them, so i cant just make a canvas eventlistener. And im really bad at javascript so i would appreciate if there was something simple.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880279/how-do-i-add-a-simple-onclick-event-handler-to-a-canvas-element

Comment: I really dont understand that... Is that really the only way of adding buttons? Isnt there anything simpler

Comment: even in 2016 I see alot of people still using Javascript. why not Jquery?