# How to set onclick event in moving object in canvas?

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, html5-canvas, html2canvas

How to set on click event in moving object in canvas? Also how to move the object bottom to top in canvas.I am newly in javascript i am going to develop the sample like when the page open, objects like square and circle randomly come from bottom of the page and move to top automatically.

Comment: Essentially, you've gotta do the heavy lifting yourself.  You need to check to see if the click location intersects with an object on the canvas.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880279/how-do-i-add-a-simple-onclick-event-handler-to-a-canvas-element

Answer (score 2):

You need to establish an array that will have your moving objects in it. When the onclick handler fires, check to see if the coordinates of the click are inside any of the objects in the array.

On each animation frame, move your objects up by subtracting some of the y coordinate from each object.

```js
//width and height of canvas...
var rW = 400;
var rH = 500;

var coinImage = getCoinImage();
var coinsOnScreen = [];
var risingSpeed = 100; //pixels per second...
var coinSize = 75;

var lastAnimationTime = 0;
var howLongUntilNextCoin = 1000;
var nextCoinOnScreen = 0;

function doDraw() {
  var can = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  can.width = rW;
  can.height = rH;
  var context = can.getContext("2d");

  //Erase the canvas
  context.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, rW, rH);

  if (new Date().getTime() - nextCoinOnScreen > 0) {

    var newX = Math.floor(Math.random() * rW) + 1;
    var newY = rH + 50;

    var newCoin = {
      x: newX,
      y: newY
    };
    coinsOnScreen.push(newCoin);
    nextCoinOnScreen = new Date().getTime() + howLongUntilNextCoin;
  }

  //Now draw the coins
  if (lastAnimationTime != 0) {

    var deltaTime = new Date().getTime() - lastAnimationTime;
    var coinRisePixels = Math.floor((deltaTime * risingSpeed) / 1000);

    var survivingCoins = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < coinsOnScreen.length; i++) {
      var coin = coinsOnScreen[i];
      coin.y = coin.y - coinRisePixels;
      //the stl variable controlls the alpha of the image            
      if (coin.y + 50 > 0) {
        context.drawImage(coinImage, coin.x, coin.y);
        //this coin is still on the screen, so promote it to the new array...
        survivingCoins.push(coin);
      }
    }
    coinsOnScreen = survivingCoins;
  }
  lastAnimationTime = new Date().getTime();
  //Wait, and then call this function again to animate:
  setTimeout(function() {
    doDraw();
  }, 30);
}

function setupClickHandler() {
  var can = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  //Here is the onclick handler
  can.onclick = function(e) {
    var x = e.clientX;
    var y = e.clientY;
    var survivingCoins = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < coinsOnScreen.length; i++) {
      var coin = coinsOnScreen[i];
      //check to see if this coin has been clicked...
      if (x > coin.x && x < coin.x + coinSize && y > coin.y && y < coin.y + coinSize) {
        //ths coin will disappear because it is not inserted into the new array...
        console.log("Coin was clicked!! " + x + " " + y);
      } else {
        survivingCoins.push(coin);
      }

    }
    coinsOnScreen = survivingCoins;
  };

}


doDraw();
setupClickHandler();

function getCoinImage() {
  var image = new Image(50, 50);
  image.src = "data:image/png;base64,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";
  return image;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```