# addEventListener mouseEvent is not working in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to add `addEventListener` on some HTML canvas element which is created dynamically. earlier it was working fine, but now none of the event working. Code below I am using -

```
this.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {...});
```

Is there any another method to register mouse event/touch event to DOM element?

[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hfaerz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by making your event listener attach to the document itself.
changing it from

```
   this.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
      console.log('mousedown called');
      event.preventDefault();
      this._setScratchPosition();
      this.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', this.scratching);
      this.callbackFun();
    });
```

to this:

```
document.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
      console.log('mousedown called');
      event.preventDefault();
      this._setScratchPosition();
      document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.scratching);
      this.callbackFun();
```

or:

```
 window.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
      console.log('mousedown called');
      event.preventDefault();
      this._setScratchPosition();
      window.addEventListener('mousemove', this.scratching);
      this.callbackFun();
    });
```

or more specifically
declare a new variable for instance 
`public c: any;`
then add

```
this.c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    this.c.addEventListener('scratch.move', () => {
      this.percent = Number(this.getPercent().toFixed(2));
      console.log('scratch.move called');
      if (this.percent > 5) {
        this.togglePrizeLabel();
      }
    });
```

and it works as advertised properly. You cannot directly reference a canvas object [How do I add a simple onClick event handler to a canvas element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880279/how-do-i-add-a-simple-onclick-event-handler-to-a-canvas-element)

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, but I need to addEventListner only on canvas element which I created dynamically.

Comment: FYI both are almost similar `document` and `window`

Comment: add a variable public c: any; add this.c = document.getElementById('js--sc--container'); and replace all of your this.canvas with your listeners with this.c and it works fine. i can edit my answer to include this if you want

Comment: I tried using your suggestion, still not working, can you fork my stackblitz demo and update their working example?

Comment: https://angular-clksyu.stackblitz.io you still need to get it to target so your scratch off works but at the very least the main function of actually changing the canvas is woring

Comment: If you closely look into the example still there are many issues, anyways I sorted out the issue with a different approach. thank you.

Comment: i am curious to which approach you used if you would post the one you used?

Comment: Not sure what was the issue, but I made it working. here is source code for the same https://stackblitz.com/edit/scractch-card-ng?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

Pls check your able to access the **this.canvas** in the class
***The alternative are as below***
1.method is to use plain javascript, grab the element by id and add an event to it

```
   // Add event listener to table
   var el = document.getElementById("outside"); 
   el.addEventListener("click",yourCustomCallBackFunction);
```

2. method is to create a directive and use it for your canvas,sample code below

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
selector: '[appChbgcolor]'
})
export class ChangeBgColorDirective {
constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {
    // this.ChangeBgColor('red');
}
@HostListener('mouseover') onMouseOver() {
    this.ChangeBgColor('red');
}
@HostListener('click') onClick() {
    window.alert('Host Element Clicked');
}
@HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() {
    this.ChangeBgColor('black');
}
ChangeBgColor(color: string) {
    this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'color', color);
 }
}
```

and later on go ahead and put the directive to youe html

```
<div appChbgcolor>
     <h3>{{title}}</h3>
</div>
```

Reference:
 [detailed description for hostListener](https://dzone.com/articles/what-are-hostbinding-and-hostlistener-in-angular)

Comment: 1. Yes `this.canvas` is accessible into the class, I have tested using logs 2. Have tried the same as well but no luck, can you try the same on Stackblitz? it's strange I have used same code many time but only this time it is not working.

Comment: Also how will you append directive to dynamically created Element?

Comment: hey,try using the directive on the sc__container tag div,from Stackblitz, html, i.e wrappping up the dynamically generated div with another where you can use the directive,

Comment: Yes, that could be a good alternate, will try. thank you for your help.