# adding a addEventListener to dynamicly created element not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following script that add a element dynamically to the canvas:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/fabric@4.0.0-rc.1/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<script id="INLINE_PEN_JS_ID">
    (function () {
        var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
        fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = false;

        fabric.loadSVGFromURL('images/hourglass.svg', function (objects, options) {

            var shape = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
            canvas.add(shape.scale(0.6));
            shape.set({ left: 200, top: 100 }).setCoords();
            canvas.renderAll();
            alert(shape.id)
        });
        shape.on('click', function () {
            alert("Handler for .click() called.");
        })
    })();
   
</script>
```

I want to get X and Y coordination of the newly created 'Shape' on click or drag with  no luck.
anyone has any suggestion.  Thanks

Comment: Please create a working snippet

Comment: Islam,  do you need to whole script including html? I am not sure what you mean by working snippet it

Comment: A working snippet is a snippet that reproduces your problem. As you can see, this doesn't execute properly https://jsfiddle.net/acyg5z8o/

Comment: Why is `shape.on('click',......` not with the code when you actually render it???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add a simple onClick event handler to a canvas element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880279/how-do-i-add-a-simple-onclick-event-handler-to-a-canvas-element)

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because `const` makes `shape` only exists inside your function.
Try this instead

```js
fabric.loadSVGFromURL('images/hourglass.svg', function (objects, options) {

            const shape = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
            canvas.add(shape.scale(0.6));
            shape.set({ left: 200, top: 100 }).setCoords();
            canvas.renderAll();
            alert(shape.id)
            
            shape.on('click', function () {
                alert("Handler for .click() called.");
            })
        });
```

**Edit**
Actually you would have had the same problem with `var` (and obviously `let`) since in javascript variable are scoped to functions

for more details have a look to [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope)

Comment: Cedric,  I made a mistake. I updated the script. The shape is var not const:
var shape = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);  and I moved the click event function inside but still not working

Comment: @user3570022 so did I... kind of... I updated my answer. It is the same with `var`. If you really want to keep `shape.on('click', ...` outside your function you should declare `shape` before `fabric.loadSVGFromURL(…`

Comment: I tried your script but it didn't work. Honestly I don't care where the function sits. inside or outside the function. as long as I get the X and Y of the element

Comment: @user3570022 the scope thing stands but another problem could be that `fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options)` doesn't return the appropriate object. What does it return ?