# Javascript unable to capture the mouse position in dedicated variables, when I can easily print it out

Tags: javascript, html, css, syntax

So, I am getting back into javascript coding, and I am resuming an older project. I am attempting to capture the mouse position in dedicated variables (mouseX and mouseY), for ease of use.

I have successfully managed to print out the mouse coordinates in real time, but when I try to place those coordinates into dedicated variables for ease of use, the program fails.

I believe this is most likely a simple syntax error, but I don't know where else to look for what I'm doing wrong.

This code fragment works correctly:

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
document.getElementById("fiddleText").innerHTML = (`Mouse X: ${event.clientX}, Mouse Y: ${event.clientY}`);

})
```

However, when I try to store the mouse position in two variables, like so:

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {

mouseX = event.ClientX;
mouseY = event.ClientY;
document.getElementByID("fiddleText").innerHTML = (`Mouse X: `+ mouseX + `Mouse Y: ` + mouseY);
})
```

the program fails.

Note: I've updated the second code fragment to fix a syntax error that was brought to my attention, but it still doesn't work.

The original second fragment looked like this:

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {

mouseX = ${event.clientX};
mouseY = ${event.clientY};
document.getElementByID("fiddleText").innerHTML = (`Mouse X: `+ mouseX + `Mouse Y: ` + mouseY);
})
```

I'd like to imagine that my question can be answered using only the code shown above, but last time I believed that, I was mistaken. As such, I have pasted my full javascript program below.

Note: This program is a work-in-progress, and there is a comment header stating "this is the problem area"; ignore this for now, that is an unrelated issue. Right now, I'm just trying to get the mouse to work.

```
//canvas elements
var canvas = document.getElementById("SnekGamCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.addEventListener('click', function () { }, false);

/*
//some code from stack overflow: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880279/how-do-i-add-a-simple-onclick-event-handler-to-a-canvas-element)
var elem = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    elemLeft = elem.offsetLeft + elem.clientLeft,
    elemTop = elem.offsetTop + elem.clientTop,
    context = elem.getContext('2d'),
    elements = [];

// Add event listener for `click` events.
elem.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    var x = event.pageX - elemLeft,
        y = event.pageY - elemTop;

    // Collision detection between clicked offset and element.
    elements.forEach(function (element) {
        if (y > element.top && y < element.top + element.height
            && x > element.left && x < element.left + element.width) {
            alert('clicked an element');
        }
    });

}, false);

// Add element.
elements.push({
    colour: '#05EFFF',
    width: 150,
    height: 100,
    top: 20,
    left: 15
});

// Render elements.
elements.forEach(function (element) {
    context.fillStyle = element.colour;
    context.fillRect(element.left, element.top, element.width, element.height);
});
*/
//End of code from stack overflow


//some important variables
var px = canvas.width / 2;
var py = canvas.height / 2;

var snekColor = "#EC942D";

var clock = 0;

var mouseX = 0.5;
var mouseY = 0.5;

//classes

class clickButton {
    constructor(text, color, width, height, radius) {
        this.text = text;
        this.color = color;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    drawButton(xpos, ypos) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000"
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;

        roundRect(xpos, ypos, this.width, this.height, this.radius, true, true, this.color);

        ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
        ctx.font = '40px san-serif';

        ctx.strokeText(this.text, xpos + 10, ypos + 40);
        ctx.fillText(this.text, xpos + 10, ypos + 40);

        //draw_Ball(303, 500, 50, snekColor);
    }

    clickOnButton() {

    }

}

//buttons

var startButton = new clickButton("Start Game", "#74B5ED", 200, 50, 20);

//images
var seel = new Image();
seel.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(seel, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
seel.src = "https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/full/086.png"

var snek_title = new Image();
snek_title.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(snek_title, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
snek_title.src = "https://globin347.com/images/Snake%20Title.png"

//stuff about mouse moving

document.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
    //document.getElementById("fiddleText").innerHTML = (`Mouse X: ${event.clientX}, Mouse Y: ${event.clientY}`);

    
    mouseX = event.ClientX;
    mouseY = event.ClientY;
    document.getElementByID("fiddleText").innerHTML = (`Mouse X: `+ mouseX + `Mouse Y: ` + mouseY);
    
})

//begin
var gameState = 0;

function draw() {

    clock += 1;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    //document.getElementById("fiddleText").innerHTML = ("Clock: " + clock);

    if (gameState == 0) {
        //this hasn't been implemented yet
        startMenu();
    }
    else if (gameState == 1) {
        //this hasn't been implemented yet either
        playGame();
    }
    else if (gameState == 2) {
        //ditto
        gameOver();
    }
    else {
        //something's wrong

        ctx.drawImage(seel, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        ctx.fillStyle = "#b30000";
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
        ctx.font = '140px san-serif';

        ctx.fillText('OH NO', 120, 120);
        ctx.strokeText('OH NO', 120, 120);

        ctx.fillText('IT BLOKE', 200, 630);
        ctx.strokeText('IT BLOKE', 200, 630);
    }

}
setInterval(draw, 10);

function startMenu() {
    ctx.drawImage(snek_title, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    /***********************************************
     * 
     * 
     * This is the problem area. When the next line, startButton.drawButton(100, 100) is commented out, the rest of the code workes normally.
     * However, if the line is not commented out, draw_Ball doesn't run, indicating that the program crashed somewhere in the button code.
     * I would like to reiterate that the button's functionality has not yet been implemented; I am only trying to get it to display.
     * 
     * 
     **********************************************/

    //startButton.drawButton((canvas.width / 2) - 100, (canvas.height * (4 / 5)));

    //flashing lights
    /*flashTime = timer % 100;
    if (timer % 2) {
        draw_Ball(200, 700, 50, snekColor);
    }*/

    draw_Ball(200, 700, 50, snekColor);
}

function playGame() {
    draw_Ball(200, 700, 50, snekColor);
    draw_Ball(400, 700, 50, snekColor);
    draw_Ball(300, 500, 50, snekColor);
}

function gameOver() {

}

//this function was stolen from stack overflow
function showImage(width, height, image_source, alt_text) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = image_source;
    img.width = width;
    img.height = height;
    img.alt = alt_text;

}

function draw_Ball(bx, by, size, ballColor) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(bx, by, size, 0, (Math.PI * 2));
    ctx.fillStyle = ballColor;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}

//This next function was taken from stack overflow

function roundRect(x, y, width, height, radius, stroke, fill, color) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x + radius, y);
    ctx.lineTo(x + width - radius, y);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y, x + width, y + radius);
    ctx.lineTo(x + width, y + height - radius);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y + height, x + width - radius, y + height);
    ctx.lineTo(x + radius, y + height);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + height, x, y + height - radius);
    ctx.lineTo(x, y + radius);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + radius, y);
    if (stroke) {
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    if (fill) {
        ctx.fill();
    }
    ctx.closePath();
    return;
}
```

And, for good measure, my HTML and CSS files:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body class="background_gradient">
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-dark dark-bg border-bottom box_shadow mb-0">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Portfolio</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <!--
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                        -->
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Resume">Resume</a>
                        </li>
                        <!----
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Art3D">3D Art</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Art2D">2D Art</a>
                        </li>
                        <!---->
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Snake">Snake</a>
                        </li>
                        
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="CodeExamples">Code Examples</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Ballad">Ballad of the Masked Bandits</a>
                        </li>
                        <!--
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="DataBaseHub">Database Hub</a>
    </li>
    --->
                        <!--
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Unavailable">???</a>
    </li>
        -->
                        <!--Temporary Links-->
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="MainDiv">
        <main role="main" class="pb-0" style="width:100%">
            <!--Where the other code goes-->
            
                @{
                    ViewData["Title"] = "Snake Game";
                }
                
                <div class="container-fluid purple_gradient text-center">
                    <h1>Snake Game</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="buffer"></div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="fancy_text_box">
                        <div class="container buffer">
                            <div class="ghostly_text_box text-center">
                                <h1>By the power of Javascript, here is a playable snake game.</h1>
                                <div class="buffer"></div>
                                <h1 id="fiddleText">Give it a moment to load.</h1>
                            </div>
                
                            <div class="buffer"></div>
                
                            <div class="ghostly_text_box text-center">
                                <canvas onload="draw()" class="simple_text_box" id="SnekGamCanvas" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
                            </div>
                
                        </div>
                
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <div class="buffer"></div>
                
                        <a class="button glo_button big_r_button big_text" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Back to Home</a>
                
                        <div class="buffer"></div>
                    </div>
                
                    <!--The code be here but if you are reading this you probably already knew that-->
                    <script src="~/js/Snake.js"></script>
                
                </div>
                
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer dark-bg text-light">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2021 - Portfolio - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="../jsc3d-master/jsc3d/jsc3d.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

...

```
/* Please see documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification
for details on configuring this project to bundle and minify static web assets. */

a.navbar-brand {
  white-space: normal;
  text-align: center;
  word-break: break-all;
}

/* Provide sufficient contrast against white background */
a {
  color: #0366d6;
}

.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-image: linear-gradient(30deg, #b6e2dd, #2a5efe);
  border-color: #1861ac;
}

/*Link colors*/
.nav-pills .nav-link.active, .nav-pills .show > .nav-link {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #1b6ec2;
  border-color: #1861ac;
}

/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html {
  font-size: 14px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  html {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

.border-top {
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
.border-bottom {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.box-shadow {
  box-shadow: 0 .25rem .75rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

button.accept-policy {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: inherit;
}

/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 60px; /* Vertically center the text there */
}

/* My Stuff
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

/*This gives me more control over the exact dark background color*/
.dark-bg
{
    background-color: #161631;
}

.purple_gradient 
{
    /*The image used*/
    background-image: linear-gradient(#4b1ac4, #fff);

    height:100%;
    width:100%;

    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.test_box_blue
{
    /* A container with a solid color and an outline */
    background-color: #2d1eb2;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;

}

.test_box
{
    border:solid #000000;
}

#MainDiv
{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;

    left:0;
    top:0;

    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.tundra_backround
{
    background-image: url('../images/Tundra_Fixed.png');
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.white_space_box
{
    height:50 px;
}

.background_gradient
{
    background-image:linear-gradient(320deg, #fff, #96cbde);
}

.glo_button
{
    min-width: 30%;
    height: 20%;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    border: 4px solid #000;
}

.big_r_button {
    background-color: #a10000;
    color: #fff;
}

.big_r_button:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #4e0505;
}

.big_b_button {
    background-color: #080e9f;
    color: #fff;
}

.big_b_button:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #161631;
}

.big_g_button {
    background-color: #0a7727;
    color: #fff;
}

.big_g_button:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #07340e;
}

.big_p_button {
    background-color: #6f1cbf;
    color: #fff;
}

.big_p_button:hover {
   color: #fff;
   background-color: #2a073e;

}

.buffer
{
    padding: 20px;
}

.big_text
{
    font-size: 60px;
    font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px rgb(12 14 39 / 0.67);
}

.fancy_text_box{
    background-image: linear-gradient(300deg, #ece1c4, #c99e69);
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 4px solid #5d3c08;
}

.simple_text_box{
    background-color: #fff;

    border: 2px solid #000;
}

.ghostly_text_box{
    background-color: rgb(255 255 255 / 0.60);
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 3px solid #000;
}

.thick_border{
    border: 4px solid #000;
}

.black_and_white_gradient{
    background-image: linear-gradient(310deg, #fff, #000);
}

.red_border{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 4px solid #8f0000;
}

.model_box{
    border: 4px solid #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

.image_box{
    border: 4px solid #000;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.chain_image_box {
    border-top: 4px solid #000;
    border-left: 4px solid #000;
    border-right: 4px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.margin_setter {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
}

#model_display_1{

}
```

I apologize for asking such a simple question, but I don't know where to look to find an existing answer.

Comment: `mouseX = ${ event.clientX };` is a syntax error.... You are trying to use template literal syntax. It should just be `mouseX = event.clientX;`

Comment: I figured it was something simple... anyway, I've made your suggested changes, but the code still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I am not sure how it does not work since you do not use the variables anywhere other than in that function.

Comment: I probably should have clarified. When I use the newer snippet, the relevant text does not change, and sometimes the background for the JavaScript program doesn’t render in the web page.

Comment: You need to use your developer console. The error is right there in plain text. Do you know how to use your developer tools in the browser and look at the console?

Comment: …apparently not. I’d better figure that out. Thank you for your time.

Comment: `document.getElementByID`

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/

Answer (score 0):

So, as I suspected, it was a simple syntax error.

Specifically, I wrote "getElementByID" instead of "getElementById". a capitalization error. (I also capitalized "clientX" and "clientY", which also broke stuff.)

I couldn't see it because I was using Visual Studio, and I couldn't find the output for the javascript. By copying the code and pasting it into JS Fiddle, I was able to actually see the errors being generated by the Javascript.

I guess that means that until I find a way to see javascript errors when running HTML code via Visual Studio, I will need to do some debugging via JS Fiddle.