# How can I add a link to dynamically created button?

Tags: javascript

Once the buttons are created, is there anyway I can add a link or use window.location method like this: `window.location = 'nextpage.html?foo=number'. I currently have this

```
var typeValue = location.search;
var typeStringValue= typeValue.replace("?type=","");
var containers = typeValue.replace("?type=multi","");
var containersValue = parseInt(containers);
var sampleLetter = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"];

function createButton(buttonName){
    var buttonDivBlock = document.getElementById("sampleSets");
    var buttonElement = document.createElement("input");
        buttonElement.setAttribute("type","button");
        buttonElement.setAttribute("name",buttonName);
        buttonElement.setAttribute("value","Sample Set"+" "+buttonName);
        buttonElement.setAttribute("id",buttonName);
        buttonDivBlock.appendChild(buttonElement);
     // document.getElementById(sampleLetter[i]).setAttribute('onclick',window.location='SampleInfo.html'+typeStringValue+bottonName);<!--add the button link -->
}

function setButtons(numberOfContainers){

     for(i=0;i<numberOfContainers;i++){
         createButton(sampleLetter[i]);

     }
}

window.onload = function(){
    setButtons(containersValue);
}
```

But `document.getElementById("'"+sampleLetter[i]+"'").setAttribute('onclick',window.location='SampleInfo.html'+typeStringValue+bottonName);<!--add the button link -->` 
returns a null value.

Comment: Possible dupes/related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789824/add-onclick-property-to-input-with-javascript, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909988/add-an-onclick-event-to-a-div,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316207/add-onclick-event-to-newly-added-element-in-javascript  . . . note that "onclick" is not a valid attribute, which is what your sample code is attempting to do.

Comment: Well its not what I'm looking for, because I've tried that and no success. :(

Comment: @ernie I've used it on other pages and stills work.

Comment: My mistake, onclick is a valid attribute . . . looks like you're not getting the element in your getElementById.  Note that in your recent edit, the code should fail as `i` won't be defined in the function . . .

Comment: Nop, no succes! but thanks a lot! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, maybe I can help you along with an example:

```
function getFive() { return 5;}

callOtherFunction("stringArgument", getFive());
```

The second argument to callOtherFunction is going to be 5, not the getFive function. In many cases, like adding event listeners and AJAX code, you actually want to pass the function itself as an argument, so it can be called later. But if you don't want to bother declaring that function seperately, it looks like this:

```
callOtherFunction("stringArgument", function() { return 5; });
```

To make code look cleaner, you can press Enter after the { and make a multi-line function.

Now, all that in mind, take another look at the line you've commented out. Do you see what's missing? (PS. Apologies for the "egging-on" format - I find people get much better at figuring things out if I help them find the solution, rather than just showing it to them)

Comment: I twisted it just a bit ;)... will post my answer and give you credit! ;)

Comment: Couldn't make my answer because of rep ... but will give it by pieces

Comment: So i followed the aproach that @Katana314 told me and added a 
`function getElementLink(buttonName){ 
            var btnLink = "window.location='SampleInfo.html?type=multi"+containersValue+"'";
            return btnLink;
    }
function createButton(buttonName){...
   buttonElement.setAttribute("onclick",getElementLink(buttonName));
        buttonDivBlock.appendChild(buttonElement);
...
}`

Answer (score 0):

The `sampleLetter` variable is not defined where you are trying to use it (judging by commented code).  Use the value you had just set to the `id` attribute a few lines earlier.

```
document.getElementById(buttonName).setAttribute( /* ... */ );
```

Or if you are trying to set it in the loop instead of in the `createButton` function, do not add the single quotes

```
document.getElementById(sampleLetter[i]).setAttribute( /* ... */ );
```

Comment: sorry I removed them while I was pasting the code here... thank you for noticing ;)

Comment: Does no success mean that `document.getElementById(sampleLetter[i])` or `document.getElementById(buttonname)` is still null?  Because you could also have additional problems preventing your code from working.  and the first step to finding the answer is making sure you are returning a non-null element with the call to `getElementById`.

Comment: Neither, and the only line that breakes my code is the `document.getElementById(buttonName).setAttribute('onclick',window.location.href='SampleInfo.html'+typeStringValue+bottonName);<!--add the button link -->`

Comment: Right, I know.  That line is calling `getElementById`.  Does that return a value?  Try splitting it into two lines.  

`var btn = document.getElementById(buttonName);`
`btn.setAttribute(...)`

Also, `bottonName` is spelled differently.

Comment: -_-...it worked :s...lol I was loosing my hair because of a simple freakin "o" ....THANK FOR NOTICING!